# wpf attached property do not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I simply want to pass parameter to the control. But it threw error "Input string was not in a correct format." Why?*                                                         *

Xaml

```
<Views:SomeView  SecurityId="abc"></Views:SomeView>
```

Model:

```
class Data
{
    public string Case { get; set; }
    public Data(int _input)
    {
        if (_input==1)
        {
            Case = "First";
        }
        else
        {
            Case = "Second";
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class DataViewModel
{
    public string GetData
    {
        get
        {
            return D.Case;
        }

        set
        {
            D.Case = value;
        }
    }

    public Data D;
    public DataViewModel(string i)
    {
        D = new Data(Convert.ToInt16(i));
    }

}
```

MainWindow

```
public partial class SomeView : UserControl
{
    public string SecurityId
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(SecurityIdProperty);
        }
        set { SetValue(SecurityIdProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty
        SecurityIdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SecurityId",
        typeof(string), typeof(SomeView),
        new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public SomeView()
    {
        DataContext = new DataViewModel(SecurityId);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: `"abc"` can't be parsed with `Convert.ToInt16(i)`.

Comment: I know, it bug. But the main problem that value of i in DataViewModel allways "". For example when i am changing //D = new Data(Convert.ToInt16(i)); with Debug.WriteLine(i);. It's printing "", instead "abc"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never listened for changes.

You construct your `DataViewModel` with the value that `SecurityId` has at the time of the constructor call. Which is the default `""`. Then you change the value to `"abc"` through XAML. But that change is not transported anywhere. It happens and nobody cares. The construction of your `DataViewModel` is already done.

Do you want to listen to changes? I cannot tell. You will need to register a change handler for your dependency property.

In your PropertyMetaData you can pass a changed event handler as second parameter, for example a static method:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty
    SecurityIdProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SecurityId",
    typeof(string), typeof(SomeView),
    new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(MyValueChanged)));
```

You can then have a method to handle changes:

```
private static void MyValueChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
   // react on changes here
}
```

It's not an attached property by the way. It's a normal dependency property.

Comment: @A191919 added a line about implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, you are trying to parse "abc" as integer, but you are not handling exceptions caused by ConvertTo.Int16() method. 

Write DataViewModel constructor like,

```
public DataViewModel(string i)
    {
        int value = 0;
        int.TryParse(i, out value); // TryParse handles the exception itself.
        D = new Data(value);
    }
```

Comment: nothing changes. Dependency property work's incorrect it always have value ""

Comment: @A191919 If you're asking why you get `Input string was not in a correct format.` error, then this answer explains the reason and thus is the correct answer. But if you're asking why `SecurityId` is always `""`, the you should edit your question.